# Empty String from Text Field In Custom UITableViewCell Class IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I created a custom class for UITableViewCell. The UITableViewCell is a dynamic prototype cell in storyboards. I am trying to reference the string from the textfield.text in my main view controller. My code in the main view controller returns nil for the textfield.text string. I know the reference to cell is correct because it will automatically populate the textfield.text, but still returns nil. Please help.

```
class AddMyLayerTitleCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addMyLayerTitleTF: UITextField!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    self.addMyLayerTitleTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.addMyLayerTitleTF.delegate = self
    
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    // This works
    print("text field text = \(addMyLayerTitleTF.text!)")

    return true
}  
}

MainViewController.m  - (objective-c)

- (IBAction)addMyLayerSaveButton:(id)sender {

    AddMyLayerTitleCell *cell = [self.gisTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddTitleCell"];
    NSString *myLayerString = cell.addMyLayerTitleTF.text;

    // Returns nil
    NSLog(@"myLayerString = %@", myLayerString);
    NSLog(@"myLayerString = %@", cell.addMyLayerTitleTF.text);
   

}
```

Comment: Hey, your "AddMyLayerTitleCell" is in Swift and you are trying to use them into an Objective-C class.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I thought it should still work but could be wrong. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Definitely, Use a single language.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the reason is something else. The code cannot work because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` can only be used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Alright vadian. I will try to use single language, Ashutosh.

Comment: place exactly above your swift class line `@objc` to make it available in objc namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ol Sen, but I ran the answer below with and without @obj and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I had to remove line `AddMyLayerTitleCell *cell = [self.gisTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddTitleCell"];` in my button. This created a new instance of the cell right before I requested the textfield string from it, so there would be nothing in the new cell's text field at the time I fetch it. I also had to declare `AddMyLayerTitleCell *cell;` outside the class so I could reference the existing cell from the button.

```
class AddMyLayerTitleCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addMyLayerTitleTF: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.addMyLayerTitleTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.addMyLayerTitleTF.delegate = self

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate  method
 textField.resignFirstResponder()

    // This works
    print("text field text = \(addMyLayerTitleTF.text!)")

    return true
}

}


// MainViewController.m  - (objective-c)

AddMyLayerTitleCell *cell;

@interface MainViewController ()


- (IBAction)addMyLayerSaveButton:(id)sender {
    
    NSString *myLayerString = cell.addMyLayerTitleTF.text;

    // Works
    NSLog(@"myLayerString = %@", myLayerString);
    NSLog(@"myLayerString = %@", cell.addMyLayerTitleTF.text);

}
```